# Fatal error during KafkaServer startup, Too many open files

Tags: apache-kafka

Unable to start kafka server, getting below exception

```
ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer) java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /kafka_2.12-2.2.0/kafka-store/kafka/cleaner-offset-checkpoint: Too many open files
            at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
            at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
            at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
            at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
            at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
            at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
            at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.<init>(CheckpointFile.scala:45)
            at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.<init>(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:57)
            at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager.$anonfun$checkpoints$1(LogCleanerManager.scala:69)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
            at kafka.log.LogCleanerManager.<init>(LogCleanerManager.scala:68)
            at kafka.log.LogCleaner.<init>(LogCleaner.scala:103)
            at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:116)
            at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1019)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:240)
            at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
            at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:75)
            at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

What cloud be the reason that exception is coming as soon as service is starting?
It was running fine and suddenly started getting this error. Open file descriptor limit was set to default which is 1024. Tried below steps, but none of these worked.

1. Increase Open file descriptor limit to 4096.
2. Did system reboot.

Finally it worked after clearing kafka data from kafka store.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

### `kafka` issues

There are severall issues that affect version `kafka v2.2`:

- [[KAFKA-9603] Number of open files keeps increasing in Streams application - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9603?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22too%20many%20files%22%20AND%20affectedVersion%20in%20(2.2%2C%202.2.0)%20), 
  see also [Small project](https://github.com/lpandzic/kafka-9603)
  replicating [the issue with same name](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9603).
- [[KAFKA-7581] Issues in building kafka using gradle on a Ubuntu based docker container - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7581?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22too%20many%20files%22%20AND%20affectedVersion%20in%20(2.2%2C%202.2.0)%20)

Some issues was fixed in [[KAFKA-7757] Too many open files after java.io.IOException: Connection to n was disconnected before the response was read - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7757)

Actually, it's not a `kafka` issue. It appears due to `linux filesystem` limitations.

### Howto check?

To debug this, try these commands:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

or

```
sysctl fs.file-max
```

Display the current soft limit:

```
ulimit -Sn
```

Display the current hard limit:

```
ulimit -Hn
```

### Howto fix?

Try to increase these values

```
ulimit -Hn <Max_files_count>
ulimit -Sn <Max_files_count>
```